# Embedded Twitter widget overflowing footer and other elements

Tags: html, css

I'm beginner at HTML and CSS and am trying to launch a simple website with an iframe from a third-party website and embedded Twitter timeline widget.

1920x1080 version looks all good, but when I use media queries to make it responsive, the Twitter timeline widget overflows on the footer or any other element that I put below it in html. Even more, it's not overflowing, it's more that the timeline starts appearing right when the footer or any other element does.

Pertinent HTML and CSS as well as a screenshot below. Thanks a lot everyone!

HTML

```
    <main>    
    <h1>ESTADO DE RED DE SUBTE</h1>
    <div class="subte-div">
      <div class="tabla">
        <iframe class="frame" height="600" src="https://aplicacioneswp.metrovias.com.ar/estadolineas/desktop.html"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="tweets">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="es" data-width="280" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/basubte?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by basubte</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </div>
    </div>  
  <footer>
    <p class="footer-text">transporte.capital, 2022</p>
  </footer>
  </main>
```

CSS

```
    .subte-div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 600px;
}

.frame {
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: rgb(208, 206, 206);
}

.footer-text {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {

  header {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .menu {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 90%;
    gap: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
  }

  .subte-div{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .tabla, .tweets {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .footer-text {
    display: none;
  }

  .h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzr0i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following CSS:

```
.subte-div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the following:

- You have `.subte-div` set to 600px of height in your css.
- Your `iframe` occupies that `600px` with `height="600"`
- Your `tweets` div is inside the .subtle-div and has `data-height="500"`

All these things can cause overflow issues because you have the `.subte-div` set to `600px` of height. And both your `iframe` and `tweets` divs are inside of it and occupy a height of that `600px` + `500px` = 1100px of height which causes an overflow..

I would suggest trying to take out the `tweets` div out of the `.subte-div` and try your best to avoid `px` values to set heights/widths as it is considered a bad practice and can cause responsiveness issues as well as in your case.. overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm learning em and rem currently so I will definitely change everything to rem/em/percentage short after launch.